# How to close a GUI on JButton click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, exit, actionevent

I have written some coding that has a GUI that has an enter button that, when clicked, opens the tool that I have created, but what I also want the jbutton to do is to close the first GUI down as well as open the tool I have created, I have tried changing the `setVisible(true/false);` statements but they just hide the GUI's and it doesnt run.

So to sum up, I want my `JButton` to have two functionalities, one to close the current GUI and one to open the tool I have created.

I think it has something to do with this coding to make the `enterButton` close the GUI:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    if(e.getSource() == enterButton){
        // coding to make the GUI exit???
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use 2 GUIs rather than a `CardLayout` or similar?  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for more details.

Comment: I'm a beginner, i have never heard of card layout @AndrewThompson

Comment: You have now, so get to a search engine and go for it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.exit(0)` like this :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    if(e.getSource() == enterButton){

        //coding to make the GUI exit???

        System.exit(0); 
    }
}
```

or use `dispose()`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    if(e.getSource() == enterButton){
        //coding to make the GUI exit???

        this.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first suggestion would only work if the 2nd GUI was started in a separate `Process`.  The 2nd suggestion might work if the 1st frame sets `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: yeah, the first suggestion closes the whole thing down including the 2nd GUI